# mongodb - index on date is not used

Tags: mongodb

Collection events has userId and an array of events-- each element in the array is an embedded document. Example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4f8f48cf5f0d23945a4068ca"),
    "events" : [
            {
                    "eventType" : "profile-updated",
                    "eventId" : "247266",
                    "eventDate" : ISODate("1938-04-27T23:05:51.451Z"),
            },
           {
                   "eventType" : "login",
                   "eventId" : "64531",
                   "eventDate" : ISODate("1948-05-15T23:11:37.413Z"),
           }
    ],
    "userId" : "junit-19568842",
```

}

Using a query like the one below tofind events generated in last 30 days:

```
db.events.find( { events : { $elemMatch: { "eventId" : 201, 
"eventDate" : {$gt : new Date(1231657163876) } } } }  ).explain()
```

Query plan shows that index on "events.eventDate" is used when the test data contains fewer events (around 20):

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor events.eventDate_1",
    "nscanned" : 0,
    "nscannedObjects" : 0,
    "n" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "indexBounds" : {
            "events.eventDate" : [
                    [
                            ISODate("2009-01-11T06:59:23.876Z"),
                            ISODate("292278995-01--2147483647T07:12:56.808Z")
                    ]
            ]
    }
```

}

However, when there are large number of events (around 500), index is not used:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
    "nscanned" : 4,
    "nscannedObjects" : 4,
    "n" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "indexBounds" : {

    }
```

}

Why is the index not being used when there are a lot of events? May be when 
there are large number of events, MongoDB finds it is efficient just to scan all the items than using the index?

Comment: You're complaining that the optimizer doesn't use the index on a query that took 0ms to return? :)

Comment: The explain output above is from a test collection. With about 20M documents, the query took about 8seconds.

Comment: Range queries like that can be slow if you're querying a significant portion of the collection's documents. You can use hint to force the index to compare speed, but I imagine it will be just as slow doing the index scan. You should post an explain from your production data, with and without a hint. The thing is, if you're finding several million documents that match, it's going to take some time to inspect them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MongoDB's query optimizer works in a special way. Rather than calculating cost of certain query plan, it just launches all available plans. Whichever returns first is considered optimal one and will be used in the future.

Application grows, data grows and changes, optimal plan may become not optimal at some point. So, mongo repeats that query selection process every once in a while.

It appears that in this concrete case, basic scan was the most efficient.

Link: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Query+Optimizer

Answer (score 2):

Using $hint to force to use index "events.eventDate", the nscannedObjects is more than w/o the index.

Pseudo code when using index:

```
for(all entries in index matching the criteria) {
  get user object and scan to see if the eventId criteria is met
}
```

all entries in index matching the criteria --> each event is an entry in the index. So the number of entries in the index will be more than the number of users. Say there are 4 user objects and a total of 7 events matching the criteria, the user object is scanned 7 times (for loop is executed 7 times). When index is not scanned, all 4 user objects are inspected only once. So using index, the number of times user object is scanned is more than when not using index. Is this understanding right?

```
db.events.find( { events : { $elemMatch: { "eventId" : 201, 
"eventDate" : {$gt : new Date(1231657163876) } } } }  )
._addSpecial("$hint",{"events.eventDate":1}).explain()

{
    "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
    "nscanned" : 7,
    "nscannedObjects" : 7,
    "n" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "indexBounds" : {

}
```